# C# PDF library to manipulate PDF

Tags: c#, pdf

our medical instrument generates patient data and images. Hospital wants to receive a PDF document which contains the patient details and images, in very specific format - A4 page, barcode on a specific place, specific page margin, etc.

I do not want to assembly this PDF from a blank canvas line-by-line in code, because if I do this I will have to write thousands of lines of code, and when we have a different customer who wants different format then we need to rewrite these thousands of lines of code again. And, if customer wants a small change in format, we need to do a new release.

I want to do it in a "mail-merge" style: I create a report template, an all-ready document with barcode, header and footer and all other static content. There are special place holders for the patient details and images in the template, something like "[@PatinetFirstName@]", "[@PatientLastName@]", "[@PatientPreviousVisitsTable@]", ... Then, for each patient, my code will make a copy of this template, find those special place holders, and replace them with real data or images. This way, if different client wants different format, all I need to do is to edit this template, my code remains the same.

This means I need to be able to use this library to do search and replace in an existing PDF, to insert paragraphs, tables and images at any place, with the capability to specify the format of the paragraphs and tables and size and resolutions of the images.

How do I do it? I mean, is there a C# API that allows me to do that?

Comment: Remember that PDF is a format for typesetting, and is not really designed for easy manipulation of text. You might want to consider working with an intermediate format (e.g. DOCX), doing your substitutions in that format and then sending the resulting document to an external PDF converter (which could be a printer driver or a standalone program, though the latter are usually proprietary and expensive to license).

Comment: I agree with Bradley, this is actually how these kind of tasks are typically done. You create an input template document in flow document type (like DOCX or HTML or ...) and after processing it you convert it into a fixed document type (like PDF or XPS or ...). In case you're interested a [GemBox.Document](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/overview) library can enable you to easily load your input template, execute a mail merge on it and save it as a resulting PDF file, as shown in this [example](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/Document/Examples/MergeFields/901).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the same task by creating txt file with placeholders:

```
This contract is an agreement between {renter}, who will be renting a house from {owner}, who owns the house being rented. 
{paragraphbreak}
The owner agrees to rent the house in its present condition located at {address} to the renter under this terms.
{paragraphbreak}
```

And created another file contract_dictionary.json, containing json which can be changed from customer to customer:

```
[
  {
    "Key": "renter",
    "Value": "John Smith"
  },
  {
    "Key": "owner",
    "Value": "Samanta Jackson"
  },
```

Then in my code I repace placeholders from tempate by values from json:

```
        ContractContent = ContractContent.ConvertAll(c => c.Replace("{paragraphbreak}", " "));
        foreach (ContractDictionary item in DictionaryData)
        {
            ContractContent = ContractContent.ConvertAll(c => c.Replace("{" + item.Key + "}", item.Value));
        }
```

Then, render it into PDF file:

```
using Gehtsoft.PDFFlow.Builder;
var s = builder.AddSection();
foreach (var paragraph in ContractContent)
            s.AddParagraph(paragraph).SetFont(DocumentFont).SetJustifyAlignment(true);
```

Here is a source code and descriptive article of this solution: [HouseRentalContract](https://go.pdfflow.io/HouseRentalContract).

To compile the above example you need to add [Gehtsoft.PDFFlowLib](https://go.pdfflow.io/PdfFlowLibraryInfo) to your project.

Hope, this will help.

Comment: This solution is essentially a recipe that could use any PDF library at the end (or at least most of them) because it does *not* work with actual PDF templates (as asked for by the OP in their question) but with plain text which thereafter is drawn in a PDF.

Answer (score 2):

You can try https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/. A brilliant library which gives power to do anything into PDF right from create, update and so many other features.Image, paragraph and tables can also be added.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check out [Html Renderer for PDFSharp (NuGet)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp/). You can use that to convert Html to PDF.

That means you can keep your templates (including @ placeholders) in your database and dynamically populate the Html template with the values and get it converted to PDF. If you later need to change the format, it's just a matter of changing the Html template.

As for searching-and-replacing, if you store your Html markup before converting to PDF, you can do search and replace in Html markup and then re-generate the PDF from the new Html markup.

Generate a PDF for sending to client. But deal with raw Html for all other system processing.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think this is the right way to go!